# CloudWatch Events Rule to skip public holidays in US

Tags: cron, amazon-cloudwatch, cron-task, crontrigger

I am trying to write a cloudwatch event / cronjob rule that triggers on every first working day of the month but if that day happens to be a public holiday in the united states then I want it to be triggered in the next working day.

Is there any way to achieve this using Cloudwatch?
Is there any way to achieve this in CRON?

If no then how are these kind of use cases solved?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Cron is very simple, so I think the best approach would be to have an event that fires on a daily basis, but which triggers a lambda. That lambda can decide if it is the first working day of the month or not. I'm assuming that there is some way to look up online if a given day is a US public holiday.